# How do get this variable to be recognised later in the method?

Tags: java, variables

Hi guys I'm writing a maths quiz program as a learning exercise and I cant get this 'response' variable to be recognised later in the method. Specifically the 'response' variable with *s either side of it does not link to the response variables declared earlier. I'm new to programming so fairly sure I'm making a basic error but I can't work it out and I'd be grateful if anyone can help me. Thanks!

```
import acm.util.*;
import acm.program.*;


public class MathsQuiz extends ConsoleProgram{

    public void run(){
        println("This program gives atudents a series of maths questions");
        askQuestions();
    }

    private void askQuestions(){
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_QS; i++){
            askQ();
        }
    }

    private void askQ(){
        int answer = rgen.nextInt(0,20);
        int number1 = rgen.nextInt(0,20);
        int number2 = answer - number1;

        if (number2 > 0){
            int response = readInt("What is " + number1 + "+" + number2 + "?");

        }else {
            int response = readInt("What is " + number1 + " " + number2 + "?");
        }

                if (**response** == answer){
                    println("Correct!");
                }else{
                    println("Incorrect");
                }
        }


    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance(); 

    int NUMBER_OF_QS = 5;
    int RES = 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm

Comment: response has scope only within the block you have declared it in. Move it's declaration to the outer block and things will work. Take care to only declare it once or you'll hide the outer declaration.

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `response` to an outer scope:

```
int response;

if (number2 > 0) {
    response = readInt("What is " + number1 + "+" + number2 + "?");
} else {
    response = readInt("What is " + number1 + " " + number2 + "?");
}
```

> Local variables have the most limited scope. Such a variable is
>   accessible only from the function or block in which it is declared.
>   The local variable's scope is from the line they are declared on until
>   the closing curly brace of the method or code block within which they
>   are declared.

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `response` outside of the `if` statement:

```
int response = -1;

if (number2 > 0) {
    response = /* ... Something ... */
} else {
    response = /* ... Something else ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it *before* the `if` statement:

```
int response;
if (number2 > 0) {
    response = ...
} else {
    response = ...
}
```

Alternatively, spot the small amount of difference between the two blocks, and change just that using a conditional operator:

```
String separator = number2 > 0 ? "+" : " ";
int response = readInt("What is " + number1 + separator + number2 + "?");
```

Answer (score 1):

its because you are creating the variable response inside of the if statement.  try this instead

```
private void askQ(){
int answer = rgen.nextInt(0,20);
int number1 = rgen.nextInt(0,20);
int number2 = answer - number1;
int response; //to create the variable in the right scope


if (number2 > 0){
    response = readInt("What is " + number1 + "+" + number2 + "?");

}else {
    response = readInt("What is " + number1 + " " + number2 + "?");
}

        if (**response** == answer){
            println("Correct!");
        }else{
            println("Incorrect");
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the value to 0 initially, when that value can never be read?

Comment: you could just put a semi colon there, but looking at his code I saw that it would not change anything and he said he was new to programming, so it might make more sense to him  that way

Comment: I would argue that any time you're specifying a value when you don't need to (and when it will never be read) you're writing misleading code. It looks like you really *want* the value to be 0 - when it's never used.

Comment: Now unfortunately the comment is technically incorrect - you're *declaring* the variable, but deliberately not actually initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

`response` is a local variable, and its accessibility is limited to inside the block in which it has been declared. So, `response` is accessible only within the `if else` block. IF you try to use `response` outside the area of scope, you will get a compile time error, until you don't redeclare it.

So, if you want to use response out of the `if else` block, you have to declare it out of the block as follows:

```
int response;
if (number2 > 0){
     response = readInt("What is " + number1 + "+" + number2 + "?");
}else {
     response = readInt("What is " + number1 + " " + number2 + "?");
}
```